# Does Phonegap support WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, cordova, webrtc, augmented-reality

I want to build an augmented reality app. I was thinking of using something like the Wikitude SDK here http://www.wikitude.com/developer or using this javascript library https://github.com/mtschirs/js-objectdetect js-objectdetect which I would prefer however, it relies on webRTC support which of course is fine using a modern browser but I'm not quite sure if PhoneGap also supports it. In addition, if anyone knows how I can superimpose my 3d models over an object, that'd be great. I don't know what file format my 3d models need to be in to be used with these augmented reality solutions.

Comment: WebRTC support is determined at the browser level. As of today newer versions of Chrome fully it, not sure what else does. Also very unlikely that mobile browsers would be supporting it as of now. Note that phonegap by default uses the native browser for its webview, meaning you cannot force phonegap into using say, Chrome as its webview.

Comment: damn, exactly what I hoped I could do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As techfoobar said, WebRTC support is determined at the **browser level**.
The WebRTC specification is **far for finished**. You can check the [current support matrix](http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream) of the draft specification. Recent versions of Firefox, Chrome and Opera supports the current implementation.

All Mobile browsers won't support it very soon. By now it works on Android with Chrome, but it's still missing on Windows IE.
The only thing you can hope for is a **phonegap plugin** which simulates the WebRTC interface.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the OpenTok PhoneGap plugin. It doesn't do WebRTC but it does do video communication. Only works with iOS right now.

https://github.com/opentok/PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: Have you tried this plug-in to stream videos? I can't tell from the doc whether if offers stream publishing or just view.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete library for android (chromium) hybrid app https://crosswalk-project.org/