# How to send a phone number to a SIP client with Cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, mobile, sip

I am developping a phone app (focusing on android for now) using Cordova, and I would like to be able to let the user call through his SIP client. For now, I am testing with Sipdroid.

This would be Sipdroid's Intent-Filters: http://pastie.org/pastes/8442254

I am trying to use WebIntent (https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent) to pass a number and launch a 'Open with...' list of compatible SIP clients. Once the user selects a client, that client would call the number passed.

I already attempted to do it with this code in Javascript:

```
//number is in the format of tel:555-555-5555
var call = function(number){
    window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
    action: android.intent.action.CALL,
    sip: number},
    function() {},
    function() {alert("Error");}); 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use [sipjs](http://sipjs.com/) to make call.Look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541882/sip-support-for-cordova-phonegap/41156014#41156014)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of the sip scheme. That 'sip:' should just contain a number like 5555555555.